# CSS - line-height padding of wrapped text not what I expect

Tags: css

Having some problems getting the correct css to align the text the way I would like.

.**html** file

```
<section id='a'>
    <div class='b'>111</div>
    <div class='b'>222</div>
    <div class='b'>33333</div>
    <div class='b'>444444 4444</div>
    <div class='b'>55555</div>
</section>
```

.**css** file

```
#a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5vw;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.b {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 56px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #696969;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

Things display fine except for **div 4** which has longer text which stretches outside.

I added a class to change the line height so the text wraps:

```
    <div class='b c'>444444 4444</div>

.c {
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

[image]

I would like to reduce the spacing between the lines so the text has a better fit inside the circle:

```
.c {
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

[image]

I like the spacing, but would like to shift the text down into the center so I added some padding inside the border:

```
.c {
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

[image]

The circle is expanded into more of an ellipse-type shape.

The height is explicitly stated as 56px.

The margin is 5px (x2 for top and bottom): 10px

The border is 2px (x2 for top and bottom):  4px

The content is two lines of wrapped text with a line height of 18px (x2): 36px

Adding padding of 6px results in 56px which is the specified height, so I am unclear why the padding would expand the height.

Looked into line-height a bit and clearly I don't really understand how that works. I have tried many other settings and values, but nothing that gives me my desired result.

Same behavior in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.

Any thoughts, direction, or clarification on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding * { box-sizing: border-box } to your CSS to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: That looks much better. I'll try tweaking things to see if I can get exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @GW by default the box-sizing is set to content-box which adds the padding etc to the pre-existing properties. Border-box includes them. [Read more about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of the divs are 56x56 pixels. Once you add any padding (`padding-top: 6px`), it will add up to 56px, which will result in 62px. Your div (circle) will become an egg. What you need to do is set `box-sizing: border-box` on the div.

Initial value of `box-sizing` is content-box. The height you enter is the content's height. Any padding and border isn't included in that value and will expand the div. `box-sizing: border-box` on the other hand, will keep the div 56px even after you enter a padding. It'll decrease the height of the content and keep the box at the same height.

```css
#a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5vw;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.b {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 56px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #696969;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.c {
    line-height: 28px;
    line-height: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<section id='a'>
    <div class='b'>111</div>
    <div class='b'>222</div>
    <div class='b'>33333</div>
    <div class='b c'>444444 4444</div>
    <div class='b'>55555</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Tweaked your solution a bit and got exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @GRW Out of curiosity, while this work, why go for a solution with fixed values when you can use a fully dynamic with less code?  This will break as soon as you change size in a responsive design or if a 3:rd line will be required.

Comment: @LGSon I'm guessing he just wanted to make the code work without using something new. Flexbox is relatively new to me, for example. I still don't know everything about it. Didn't need it that much. But, you're right. Yours would have been a better solution.

Comment: @akinuri Thanks ... just curious why, but we'll see what answer I get (and there are other ways than `flex` doing this dynamic)

Comment: @LGSon - akinuri is precisely right, flexbox was completely foreign to me whereas box-sizing was easy for me to comprehend and implement. This is a work in progress and responsive design might later require me to rethink my approach, but for now this minor issue is behind me while I move on to other bigger issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` is a good solution for vertical alignment, regardless of the properties of the child element.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.three {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container one">
  <span>some text</span>  
</div>

<div class="container two">
  <span>some other text</span>  
</div>

<div class="container three">
  <span>some text that stretches longer</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`padding` counts toward element size. So `height: 56px` and `padding-top: 6px` will make the element `62px` high. Just adjust the `height` of that element to `50px` (desired height minus vertical padding, 56 - 6).

Another option is to change `box-sizing` to `border-box` (default value is `content-box`). Which will make `padding` and `border-width` to be considered by `width` and `height` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
.b {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

and add a wrapper with

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox`, where there is no need to calc lines and match padding against size, this does it all dynamically.

```css
#a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5vw;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.b {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #696969;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id='a'>
    <div class='b'>111</div>
    <div class='b'>222</div>
    <div class='b'>33333</div>
    <div class='b'>444444 4444</div>
    <div class='b'>55555</div>
</section>
```